# Remove hash tags from multiple tabs menu and else where

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to get rid of tags from the tabs menu.. looking at other solutions I realize that I need to include return false; in my code, however I am not certain where I need to include it. Below is the code, if anyone can point me how exactly should I get rid of the hash tags, it would be really great.

```
(function (a) {
    a.fn.extend({
        tabify: function (e) {
            function c(b) {
                hash = a(b).find("a").attr("href");
                return hash = hash.substring(0, hash.length - 4)
            }
            function f(b) {
                a(b).addClass("active");
                a(c(b)).show();
                a(b).siblings("li").each(function () {
                    a(this).removeClass("active");
                    a(c(this)).hide()
                })
            }
            return this.each(function () {
                function b() {
                    location.hash && a(d).find("a[href=" + location.hash + "]").length > 0 && f(a(d).find("a[href=" + location.hash + "]").parent())
                }
                var d = this,
                    g = {
                        ul: a(d)
                    };
                a(this).find("li a").each(function () {
                    a(this).attr("href", a(this).attr("href") + "-tab")
                });
                location.hash && b();
                setInterval(b, 100);
                a(this).find("li").each(function () {
                    a(this).hasClass("active") ? a(c(this)).show() : a(c(this)).hide()
                });
                e && e(g)
            })
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

the html code for the above

```
<ul id="menu">
<li href="#tab-1">Tab 1</li>
<li href="#tab-2">Tab 2</li>
<li href="#tab-3">Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="content"></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="content"></div>
<div id="tab-3" class="content"></div>
```

Comment: really not clear what you want. Suggest providing some html and explain by referencing the html

Comment: I just want to get rid of the html tags that get added on to the end of the url after anyone clicks on the tabs... I am updating the html for the tags...

Comment: suggest you get a different tab script then. The one you have hinges on the hashes to allow bookmarking active tab

Comment: Could you recommend any?

Comment: Can anyone recommend other tabs.. that are not hinged on hash tags?

Comment: use google..lots to be found